# How to update the data in child routes when the data in parent changes

Tags: angular

How to update the data in child routes when the data in parent changes

```
path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent, 
    resolve: {profileDetails: ProfileDetailsResolverService}, 
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: DashboardHomeComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full',
        },

        {
            path: 'my-profile',
            component: MyProfileComponent,
            resolve: { profileDetails: ProfileDetailsResolverService }
        },
        {
            path: 'web-development',
            component: WebDevComponent,
        },

    ]
}
];
```

In the prolife component the user can update his profile pic and all the other details like name. The dashboard component has header which is shown on all the child components. The header has things like name and profile pic and if the user changes this name and profile pic I use a service to update the data in the DashboardComponent as follows.

In the profile component

```
if profile is changed() {
     this.comService.updated.next(true);
}
```

In the dashboard component

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 ngOnInit() {
    //the communication service is triggered from profile component and so it 
    updates the data in the header.
    this.comService.updateState.subscribe((r)=>{
      if(r) {
        this.auth.getUserProfile().subscribe((res: any)=>{
          this.userDetail = res.data;
          this.avatarUrl = this.data.siteLink()+this.userDetail.avatar;
        });
      }
    });
 }
}
```

Now if I go to the WebDevComponent using the router link then I see the old profile data there. The data only updates when i hard refresh the page. This is how I get the data in WebDevComponent using .parent

```
        export class WebDevComponent implements OnInit {
        constructor(private auth: AuthService, private activeRoute: 
        ActivatedRoute, 
        private router: Router) {
        activeRoute.data.subscribe((res)=> {
          this.userDetail = res.profileDetails.data;
        })
       }
          userDetails: any;
          ngOnInit(){
            this.activatedRoute.parent.data.subscribe((data: any)=>{
              this.userDetails = data.profileDetails.data;
            });
          }
         }
```

Now offcourse if I use `resolve: { profileDetails: ProfileDetailsResolverService }` in the WebDevComponent's routing and instead of parent use `this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data: any)` then the data will update when going to that route because that sends a new api request and fetches the data but its inefficient to make another api/server request.

Answer (score 2):

Try Adding runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' to child config

```
path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent, 
        resolve: {profileDetails: ProfileDetailsResolverService}, 
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: DashboardHomeComponent,
                runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
                pathMatch: 'full',
            },

            {
                path: 'my-profile',
                component: MyProfileComponent,
                runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
                resolve: { profileDetails: ProfileDetailsResolverService }
            },
            {
                path: 'web-development',
                component: WebDevComponent,
                runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
            },

        ]
    }
    ]
```

And Add onSameUrlNavigation?: 'reload' to route Config

```
RouterModule.forRoot([.., {
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
  }) ]
```

Comment: Didnt thought it'd work but it worked. thanks. Does  it make the parent component refresh the data by making the backend request each time you change the routes.

Comment: I noticed it works without  `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' `

Comment: It works but doesn't have any benefit. It makes api request every time the route changes. My purpose to use .parent was so that it fetches the data thats already there in the parent without making the request or at least make request only when there is change in the data

Comment: I was not using parent to fetch data in that route so i had resolved in that route which was bad since on hard refresh same api would be called 2 times one in myprofile and other in dashboard. Using parent limits it to 1

Comment: Try to remove runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' in DashboardComponent